# How to get the element made (not target) the event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a class='tagselector' style="width=100px;height:100px">
<div style="margin-top:12px;">
MyName
</div>  
</a>
```

In the above Mark up if I made a script as shown below (in ready() function)

```
$(".tagselector").click(function(clickevt){
console.log($(clickevt.target));
});
```

`$(clickevt.target)` This will return either `<div>` or `<a>` Tag upon click. I want to get the  tag that made this click.

NB: Please edit the question if necessary!

Comment: what do you want on click is not clear. Please be more clear

Comment: I think you want `$(this)`.

Comment: A tag doesn't "make" the click - the human does. Exactly what result do you want here?

Comment: Inside the <a> tag you can see a div tag. If the user made click on <div> tag the event.target will be the <div>. But I always want the <a> tag made the click

Comment: That would be $(this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `currentTarget`:

```
$(".tagselector").click(function(clickevt){
    console.log($(clickevt.currentTarget));
});
```

Or simply use `this` keyword in your script:

```
$(".tagselector").click(function(clickevt){
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Comment: `event.currentTarget === this` Will this condition always happen to be true?

Answer (score 1):

i assume this is what you need

```
$(".tagselector").click(function(clickevt){
if (clickevt.target == this)
    //your stuff
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/WFRQY/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".tagselector").click(function(clickevt){
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your question..This probably would help :

```
$(".tagselector").click(function(clickevt){
    console.log($(this)[0].tagName; );
});
```

Comment: `$(this)` will be always one element right? why `$(this)[0]` added?

Comment: There is no need to convert `this` to jQuery object and get it back again. You could write `this.tagName` instead.

Comment: Ya, but I was asking about `[0]`?